# shared data without using mutable variables

Tags: functional-programming

I may not have the right vocabulary for this question, but I'm looking to understand a fundamental concept of functional programming. Thank you for reading!

If you write a purely functional program that interacts with *multiple consumers*, how do you model *shared* information? Using the example of a bank account...

With mutable variables, you can do something like this:

```
class BankAccount {

  private var bal: Int = 0

  def balance: Int = bal

  def deposit(amount: Int) {
    bal += amount
  }

  def withdraw(amount: Int) {
    bal += amount
  }
}
```

So if the balance was $0 at t0 and Bob deposits 5 at t1, then Mary checks the balance at t2, she sees 5, that is she sees the effect of Bob's action.

How would you implement this with functional programming, where variable are supposed to be immutable? I can understand that with a *single* consumer, Bob, you can return a *new* instance of BankAccount with a balance of 5. But with a second consumer, Mary, how *would she access this new BankAccount*?

Conceptually, one can think about balance not as a state that changes over time, but rather there is an immutable balance_t0 = 0 and an immutable balance_t1 = 5. But to do this, you would still need some way to *name* the balance at each point in time in your programming language...

Comment: You would need a global state where Mary can only access the new instance that Bob created not the old one.

Comment: Does that mean "there is no way to do this using immutable variables"?

Comment: No, it means you cannot do this without state. You can even model that state with immutable values.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example using only immutable values? I was trying to figure out how to do this, but as I describe in my last two paragraphs, I was not able to figure it out when it comes to having multiple consumers.

Comment: This is Scala, right? Check out the [state monad](https://www.google.com/search?q=scala+state+monad).

Comment: OK, given that there's a ton for me to unpack there (which I do plan on doing), is it effectively not possible to demonstrate how to implement this type of program using immutable variables unless I have clarity around monads and the state monad?